# Apache - Which auth to use?

Tags: php, apache, authentication

I have a Linux server (CentOS 5) generating reports, and I would like to present each user its own report automatically (they work with Windows -> Internet Explorer).

Users are controlled by a dc (that I don´t maintain), and I would like to retrieve their domain user when they access this web server, so they don´t have to fill any login prompt. I thought maybe PHP $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] would be useful, but it does not return any value.

Is it necessary to use authentication to retrieve REMOTE_USER? In my case, all I need is the username, and later I'll check if there's any report for the user. Which would be the best option? Because I've seen a lot of modules: kerberos, ntlm, sspi... and don´t know which one to use or which one would be suitable in this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used `mod_auth_ntlm` to authenticate users in domain transparently

Answer (score 0):

Q: `Is it necessary to use authentication to retrieve REMOTE_USER?`

A: You can refer to [RFC 3875 - The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) Version 1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875)

> The REMOTE_USER variable provides a user identification string
>     supplied by client as part of user authentication.
>
> ...
>
> If the client request required HTTP Authentication [5] (e.g., the
>     AUTH_TYPE meta-variable is set to "Basic" or "Digest"), then the
>     value of the REMOTE_USER meta-variable MUST be set to the user-ID
>     supplied

This means, that remote user is reliably set only if the client passes authentication data along with the request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer hek2mgl. So I need to authenticate users if I want REMOTE_USER to be set. I'm currently checking ntlm (thanks zerkms) but there are a few options... http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/mod_auth_winbind-for-apache-in-centos-748125/   I've read about ntlm with winbind, but it uses kerberos. Is this the "standard" mod?

Comment: I have never tried this. Reading the article you've linked I would say that `mod_auth_winbind` would be the way to go. But I'm not sure. Would like to hear if it's working for you after all and what is the solution. Also note that using client site ssl certificates is a nice way to authenticate and identify users